# How to convert latitude and longitude into string

Tags: google-maps, laravel-5

I have a Geo Location for my google map. In my query, i want to retrieve all possible rows that match to my input type address like (city address)
but i dont know how to compare the INPUT to the lat and long column from the database.

```
scholar_table
id   name           gender          lat                 long
1    John           Male        10.295866           123.889362
2    Joseph         Male        10.352621           123.914448
3    Genrevel       Female      10.331987           123.91059989999997



///controller
public function address(Request $request){

    //sample input CEBU

    $scholars = (new Scholar)->newQuery()->select('*');

    $scholars->where('gender', '=', Input::get('gender'));



    $scholars = $scholars->get();

    }
```

Comment: Neither do we: do you want to find the nearest to a point? Display entries on a map with a bounding box? Find the shortest route? Something else?

Comment: @symcbean - Sir ,what i want is to convert the lat and long  to string from the database which is i am going to use to compare in the  input address.If there is a word like London that matches from the input to the converted string, i'l get that value.